# Aligning text beside a radio/checkbox in HTML

Tags: html, css, radio-button

There is some padding from the top to the `Keep me logged in` text.
[image]

How can I remove the padding and make it look like this ? 
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="login-radio">
<input type="radio">Keep me logged in
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.login-radio {  
font-size: 12px;
position: fixed;
left:60%;
top: 7%;
color: white;
font-family: arial;   
}
```

Comment: Your "Keep me Logged in" should be a `checkbox`, not a `radio`.

Comment: try `vertical-align: middle` on input

Comment: Same problem with a `checkbox`

Comment: The code posted does not produce the rendering in the image. Both HTML and CSS code is missing.

Comment: Is just me or the images seemed identical?

Comment: @MavenMaverick Please checkout the answers below and mark one as accepted that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div>

  <div class="email">
     <input type="email" />
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <span>Keep me logged in</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.email input {
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
outline: none;
}

.checkbox input {
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 5px;                                      
color: #000;
clear: both;
}

.checkbox span {
float: left;
margin-top: 7px;
margin-left: 2px;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLr8e952/).

Regards, Milan.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="login-radio radio">
       <input type="radio" class="radio">
       <label>Keep me logged in </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.login-radio, .login-checkbox, .radio, .checkbox {
    display: block;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    line-height: normal;
}

.radio label, .checkbox label {
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you want exactly the position of your radio button to be or something else

.login-radio input {
    `vertical-align:top;margin-top:1px;`

}

http://jsfiddle.net/we9x6k3j/1/

Answer (score 0):

*3 steps that will fix your problem:*

- Remove the default `margin` and `padding` that the browser applies to the `<input>` by default.
- Wrap the text in a `<label>`.
- Apply `vertical-align: middle` to the `<input>` and the `<label>`.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
.login-radio {  
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  left:60%;                                     
  top: 7%;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial;   
}

input{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

input, label{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <label>Keep me logged in</label> <!-- wrap the text in a label -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/we9x6k3j/3/)

**CSS:**

```
.login{
    width: 200px;
    height:80px;
    background-color: brown;
    color: white;
}

.loginInput{
    margin-left: 3%; 
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.loginRadio input{
    margin-left: 3%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Key change is the vertical alignment of loginRadio input.